# Android Studio does not show layoutpreview

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create a layout in Android Studio but the preview of the layout is not showing at all. There is no errour though.

How can i get it to work properly? I will add a screenshot.

Preview not loading the layout

[image]

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.diceout.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Let's Play!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/rollButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="155dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="155dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Roll" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

TextView

[image]

Comment: have you tried to build the project?

Comment: Did you add support library in gradle?

Comment: Post your code too

Comment: What is the support library? New to this program

Comment: post the code for content_main there will be separate files for views, check into app > res > layout

Comment: I edited it and posted it

Comment: select text option next to design and post the screenshot so we can check whether its correct or not.

Comment: I added a link to the screenshot of the textview

Comment: @ivanfranken do You try to use coordiantor layout ?

Comment: try build > clean project and after build successful open preview

Comment: Clean an Build did not work.

Comment: What is the coordiantor layout? New to this.

Comment: it is a layout like relative layout. it will be in one of your layout xml files.

Comment: Make sure you compile the correct versions of the necessary libraries

Answer (score 0):

@ivan franken Could you post your @layout/activity_main Xml code. I saw this line `tools:showIn:@layout/activity_main` 
in code on your content_main.xml. I tested it in my project and got similiar result to yours. But when I deleted it, it worked fine.